# Doctrine 2.1 - query counting

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Is there any class / method in Doctrine 2.1 that counts amount of queries done by particular entity manager (or sth else?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. That would require some kind of persistence to store the number of times the queries are executed. You could always enable the log (disabled by default on production), use a custom logger like [Monolog](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/logging/monolog.html) and parse the logs afterwards, or use a tool like [NewRelic](http://newrelic.com/) that gives you real-time and historical data of things like database queries (among a lot of other useful features).

Comment: Agreed, use a log. I'm using Kohana with Doctrine and the module already has a log for development settings. I guess there should similar simple solution for Symphony. Here is Kohana module if you are interested https://github.com/Flynsarmy/KODoctrine2/blob/master/modules/doctrine2/classes/logger/doctrine2.php